# In NetBeans, how to change the colors of the hint tooltips

Tags: netbeans, color-theme, netbeans-7.3

I use a dark theme for my desktop and for Netbeans, but the hint tooltip in NetBeans are displayed with white background and grey foreground.
I really need to change them because it's unreadable with these colors.
I was looking in the Options -> Fonts & Colors but I didn't find anything.

Comment: I'm bumping into this as I have the exact same problem. Everything else is fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIManager.put("ToolTip.background", new Color(240,240,240));
```

Further Reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html

Comment: Although this may answer the question, you should give a more detailed description of the linked content and explain how it relates to the question. This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page goes is removed or goes offline. For more information, see [this Meta Stack Exchange post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259).